# Implicit typecasting - Int to double

Tags: java, casting, implicit-conversion

I've got an excercise from university which looks like:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 3;

double c = a / b;
```

The question is: Which value is c.

Now I would say, c is 3.3. It's casted implicit to double before calculating the result.
But the correct answer to this question is according to my records 3.0.

How this can be? Does the compiler really calculate the result first as integer and then in a second step casts it to double?

Or did I understand that incorrectly?

Comment: You answered yourself "the compiler really calculate the result first as integer and then in a second step casts it to double"

Comment: _"Does the compiler really calculate the result first as integer and then in a second step casts it to double?"_ yes it is.

Comment: Try changing the type of either a or b to double. Then, the type casting (of the other operand) will be performed before the division instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the compiler really calculate the result first as integer and
>   then in a second step casts it to double?

Yes

Comment: 2 things: 1st - your avatar with the hat is just badass! 2nd - this is my favorite SO answer :)

Comment: answer the second question _"Or did I understand that incorrectly?"_ and this will be perfect

Answer (score 3):

> Does the compiler really calculate the result first as integer and
>   then in a second step casts it to double?

Yes,

Runtime first calculates the RHS result and then converts the result to `double`. Now in your case as RHS contains `int / int` so the result is in `int` and you don't get `3.3`.

So if RHS contains `double / int` or `int / double`, the type promotion occurs and RHS operands are promoted to double before calculating the result and hence you get 3.3

Answer (score 1):

See what is actually happening is :

```
double c = (double)    a / b; //double of 3 = 3.0
```

you have to do

```
double c = a/(double)b
```